# Draggable div inside a rotated parend div?

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, rotation, draggable, drag

i want to drag items around inside a div that is rotatable, but it doesnt work correctly

anyone knows how to fix that? Here is the code

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left:20px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    -moz-transform: rotate(80deg);
     transform: rotate(80deg);
}
.inner{
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    left:20px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/27ey90xw/